# How to print updated documents of Mongodb in my console using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am reading a csv file if id matches it will update documents in my mongodb.But when i am printing the updated documents all are printing.below is the code.

```
const Account = require('./Account'); 
const parse = require('csv-parse');
const fastcsv = require("fast-csv");
const json2csv = require('json2csv').parse;
var csvWriter = require('csv-write-stream')
var newColumnValue = 'insertsuccessfully'; 
var writer = csvWriter()
let csvData = [];  
var csvData1 = [];
const fs = require('fs');

var name = [];
fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/node_insert_2_1.csv').pipe(
parse({
    delimiter:',',
    from_line: 2
})
 )
     .on('data',function(dataRow) {
      var customerid = dataRow[1];
       
        Account.findOne({customerId: customerid}).then(
        function(doc)
        {
            if(doc)
            {
                const updatedata =
                 {};

                 updatedata.InternalId=dataRow[0],
                 updatedata.firstname=dataRow[2],
                 updatedata.lastname =dataRow[3],
                 updatedata.email=dataRow[4],
                 
                 updatedata.phone=dataRow[5],
                 updatedata.mobilePhone =dataRow[6],
                 updatedata.primary=dataRow[7]
                const docid = doc._id;
                Account.findByIdAndUpdate(docid,updatedata,{upsert:true}).then(
                             function(doc3)
                             {
                               
                              
                                
                               console.log("Updated User : ", doc3); 
                           
                             }
                               
                        );
            
           
              
             
   
             
             console.log(docid)
             
             }
```

As i am printing   console.log("Updated User : ", doc3);  all data of csv is printing inform of json. But i need only updated data to be printed into my console

Answer (score 0):

The findByIdAndUpdate function will return the entire document, not just the updates.

If there is no error, it is safe to assume that the update was successful, so you could just print the updatedata object?